# Jenkins iOS Submit app Crashlytics failed (with Xcode Integration plug-in)

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, jenkins, crashlytics

Jenkins grab my source from git and compile and generate a build is working fine. But when I run the Crashlytics command in Execute Shell to submit the build to Crashlytics Beta, it failed.

Error I received:

```
2016-06-02 13:52:05.232 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit  
1.3.5 (17)

2016-06-02 13:52:07.405 submit Crashlytics: Unable to package source due to 
error: Error Domain=CLSIPABuilderErrorDomain Code=-6 "(null)" UserInfo= 
{UnderlyingError=Error Domain=CLSCodeSignerErrorDomain Code=-2 "(null)" 
UserInfo={arguments=(
"--sign",
B0DC1AA9228E7CB89E7ACE1576AEF3B1EC166012,
"--all-architectures",
"--force",
"--entitlements",

"/var/folders/k5/656qxxbs6854_mdjb53j2gp80000gn/T/com.crashlytics.ipas/991D8904-72CA-4B9C-A9D7-377F9D8420FF/Payload/entitlements.xml",
"/var/folders/k5/656qxxbs6854_mdjb53j2gp80000gn/T/com.crashlytics.ipas/991D8904-72CA-4B9C-A9D7-377F9D8420FF/Payload/elevenstreet.app"
), environment={
"CODESIGN_ALLOCATE" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate";
}, status=1, stderr=B0DC1AA9228E7CB89E7ACE1576AEF3B1EC166012: no identity found
, command=/usr/bin/codesign, stdout=}, SourcePath=/var/folders/k5/656qxxbs6854_mdjb53j2gp80000gn/T/com.crashlytics.ipas/991D8904-72CA-4B9C-A9D7-377F9D8420FF}
2016-06-02 13:52:07.452 submit Crashlytics: Failed to prepare the binary for release

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Shell code is from its [doc](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/beta/build-tools.html).

Not sure where it goes wrong. Please help.

Comment: "no identity found" see [CodeSign collisions between Developer and Enterprise Distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203605/390177)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without changing anything on Keychain and distribution cert, and settings on Jenkins and Xcode Integration plugins, delete the existing Jenkins project and make a new one and re-assign all the settings and everything works.**

Things to take note:

- Make sure to have latest version of Crashlytics and Fabrics frameworks.
- Make sure distribution cert in in your Keychain.
- In Jenkins, in Xcode Integration plugin, under **Code signing & OS X keychain options**, make sure your **Code Signing Identity** is your certificate name (exactly the name of your distribution cert), and you can left **Embedded Profile** blank for it to point to the default location.
- Tick Unlock **Keychain option**, and it will expand its panel. Make sure the path of Keychain is correct. Default is /Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/.keychain, and the password. Default password would be your password that you use to sign in into your computer.
- And Lastly, the Crashlytics command:

  ```
  ${WORKSPACE}/Pods/Crashlytics/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API Key> <Build Secret Key> -ipaPath ${WORKSPACE}/ipa-dir/<project_name>-${BUILD_ID}.ipa -emails <your_email>  -notifications YES
  ```